# Problem in special character reading from file in python

Tags: python

I am having a problem in file reading in python. I have a file that has some Unicode characters like below.

**Test_data.txt :**

```
ý[þ»¢5åÆ¢Nde¼Èó!`Å6^
```

But when I am trying to read the file some extra characters get appended with the text like below.

```
ý[þ»¢5\x1få\x8fÆ\x0f¢Nde¼Èó!\x0c`Å6\x1d\x1a^
```

**My code is below:**

```
main_data_full = []
main_file = open("Test_data.txt", "r", encoding = 'utf-8') 

main_data = []
for line in main_file:
    main_data_full.extend(line.split("\n"))

print(main_data_full)
```

I don't want to get the extra "\x" type characters in between the text. Can anyone help me to solve the code.

Comment: \xNN is just python's way of displaying unprintable characters.  What is this data?

Comment: Just tell me how can I read the file without the "\x" texts. If I can get the values in hexadecimal, that will also be ok.

Comment: If it's binary data, open it in binary mode, and deal with in byte strings.  Don't print it.  print() is for human readable data.  You can use read() and write() to deal with byte string then.  The \x characters aren't *extra*, they're characters that can't be printed to a console.

Answer (score 0):

An opened Python file is iterable, line by line, so you don't need to split lines yourself or use `extend()`.

For example, suppose we have this file:

```
some data
ý[þ»¢5åÆ¢Nde¼Èó!`Å6^
blah
blah2
```

A small program:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as fh:

    # One way to read the lines.
    lines = []
    for line in fh:
        lines.append(line)

    # Another.
    # lines = list(fh)

    # And another.
    # lines = fh.readlines()

print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['some data\n', 'ý[þ»¢5åÆ¢Nde¼Èó!`Å6^\n', 'blah\n', 'blah2\n']
```

Comment: Just tell me how can I read the file without the "\x" texts. If I can get the values in hexadecimal, that will also be ok.